# Better design pattern for allowing callbacks to access parent function data

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am using async's eachSeries method to scrape an array of RSS feeds, and then building an object to pass to async's waterfall method (not featured in the code).

To allow the callback to call the next() function, and to allow the array of RSS feeds to be built, I am making them accessible globally on the window object.

I can't help but feel there is a better way to design this without going full pyramid and also using best practices to avoid variable collision.

Here is the code:

```
var async = require('async');
var parser = require('rssparser');
// let me know if you would like me to post the rssFeeds array object

var numberOfItemsToScrape = 1

// receives the scraped data and builds the object
function loadData(err, data){
  var items = [];

  for (var i = 0; i <= numberOfItemsToScrape - 1; i++) {
    items.push(data.items[i])
  }

  feedToMutate.items = items

  rssFeedsToExport.push(feedToMutate)
  nextFunction();
}

// scrapes the data and passes it to a callback
function scrapeRss(rssFeed){
  parser.parseURL(rssFeed.url, parserOptions, loadData)
}

// calls async.eachSeries on the rssFeeds array
function scrapeRssAndLoadData(rssFeeds, cb){
  rssFeedsToExport = []

  async.eachSeries(rssFeeds, function(feed, next) {
    scrapeRss(feed);

    feedToMutate = feed
    nextFunction = next
  }, 
  function (err) {
    // when used in the context of the async.waterfall pattern, 
    // this will look like cb(null, rssFeedsToExport)
    console.log(rssFeedsToExport);
  });
}

scrapeRssAndLoadData(rssFeeds, cb)
```

Is there a better way to design this code to avoid variable collision?

Comment: I take it this is a follow-up question on what you were working on?

Comment: Yes, basically I've designed a  working module but certain things feel either too hacky or too insecure to be really satisfied with. Over the next few days I'll probably post another time or two with a pattern/design that intuitively feels improper and ask the community if they have a pointer or two to offer me. Haha that's the plan at least.

Comment: I would consider posting a summary on the codereview stackexchange of your work, you'll likely get more relevant feedback there on improvements you can make if there's not actually an error.

Comment: Wow, mind blown. Had not actually realized that such a stackexchange existed. I'll definitely check that out, it does seem like perhaps it would fit better given the format of my question(s).

Comment: you can use bind() to stick something onto a function instance, instead of globals. or you can wrap an anon around you code to prevent globals.

Comment: Right, I think that method will work actually. I'll have a chance to throw some time at it in a couple hours and will let you know how it goes, thanks.